# How to update ExoPlayer's progress bar while playing video on CastPlayer Android?

Tags: android, chromecast, exoplayer2.x

I have a doubt regarding the ExoPlayer and CastPlayer. 
When I cast a video on the castplayer the progressbar on exoplayer is not being updated, also the remaining and the timme elapsed on exoplayer is not updating.
I want to enable the functionality that will control the video (like play, pause, forward, rewind) from the exoplayer while the video is being played on the castPlayer.
Also the exoplayer video view should show the text "Casting on "
These are the dependecies

```
implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:2.11.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.3'
```

Can someone point me to an example implementation about the same?

I have gone through these example https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos,  https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android

Comment: I also have the same issue for the progress bar. Could you find a solution for this?

Comment: I did it by using the ExpandedControllerActivity present in the Cast Demo and then adding a listener to the mediaClient and onStatusUpdated just hide the current views which are not needed and open ExpandedControllerActivity. Although this is not a concrete solution but just a work around. I am still looking for a concrete solution.